# Delphi sql utilizando coalesce

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, delphi-7

No delphi tenho TIBQuery:

```
select * from TB_PRECO
where
coalesce(DT_CAMPANHA,'') = coalesce(:DT_CAMPANHA,coalesce(DT_CAMPANHA,'')) and
coalesce(DT_VECTOPRECO,'') >= coalesce(:DT_ATUAL, coalesce(DT_VECTOPRECO,'')) and
DESC_GRUPO = coalesce(:DESC_GRUPO, DESC_GRUPO) and
TP_CAMPANHA = :TP_CAMPANHA and
UF_CAMPANHA = coalesce(:UF_CAMPANHA, UF_CAMPANHA) and
DESC_PRODUTO LIKE coalesce(:DESC_PRODUTO, DESC_PRODUTO) and
COD_PRODUTO = coalesce(:COD_PRODUTO, COD_PRODUTO)
order by DESC_PRODUTO
```

passo os seguintes parâmetros:

```
IBQCons_Preco.ParamByName('COD_PRODUTO').Value := Unassigned;
IBQCons_Preco.ParamByName('DESC_PRODUTO').Value := '%%';
IBQCons_Preco.ParamByName('DESC_GRUPO').Value := 'INSETICIDAS';
IBQCons_Preco.ParamByName('DT_ATUAL').Value := StrToDate('23/03/2018');
IBQCons_Preco.ParamByName('TP_CAMPANHA').Value := 'REAIS';
IBQCons_Preco.ParamByName('DT_CAMPANHA').Value := StrToDate('18/05/2018');
IBQCons_Preco.ParamByName('UF_CAMPANHA').Value := Unassigned;
```

Ao executar o programa funciona. O porém esta quando tento executar no IbExpert:

```
select * from TB_PRECO
where
coalesce(DT_CAMPANHA,'') = coalesce('18.05.2018',coalesce(DT_CAMPANHA,'')) and
coalesce(DT_VECTOPRECO,'') >= coalesce('23.03.2018', coalesce(DT_VECTOPRECO,'')) and
DESC_GRUPO = coalesce('INSETICIDAS', DESC_GRUPO) and
TP_CAMPANHA = 'REAIS' and
UF_CAMPANHA = coalesce(null, UF_CAMPANHA) and
DESC_PRODUTO LIKE coalesce('%%', DESC_PRODUTO) and
COD_PRODUTO = coalesce(null, COD_PRODUTO)
order by DESC_PRODUTO
```

O sql não me retorna nem um registro. Agora se eu fizer assim:

```
select * from TB_PRECO
where
DT_CAMPANHA = '18.05.2018' and
DT_VECTOPRECO >= '23.03.2018' and
DESC_GRUPO = 'INSETICIDAS' and
TP_CAMPANHA = 'REAIS' and
UF_CAMPANHA = coalesce(null, UF_CAMPANHA) and
DESC_PRODUTO LIKE '%%'
and COD_PRODUTO = coalesce(null, COD_PRODUTO)
order by DESC_PRODUTO
```

O SQL me retorna os mesmos registro que o primeiro SQL da TIBQuery. 
Alguém já passou por algo parecido.

Solução:
 No sql utilizar o CAST(), exemplo: Cast('18.05.2018' as Date).

Comment: Palite, no `coalesce(DT_CAMPANHA,'')` você altera um campo `Date` para `Varchar`.  
Tente como teste fazer `coalesce(DT_CAMPANHA,'01.01.2000')` por exemplo, aí continuará sendo uma data...

Comment: UF_CAMPANHA = coalesce(null, UF_CAMPANHA) -> neste caso a expressão pode retornar "null" e, assim, o operador deveria ser "is null" e não "="

Comment: @RicardoAlvesCarvalho creio que não seja esse o problema pois no ultimo sql eu passo UF_CAMPANHA = coalesce(null, UF_CAMPANHA), o sql esta trazendo registros.